# image is too big for OpenCV imshow window, how do I make it smaller?

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface

I'm comparing two images - a complete image & a small part of the same image. If a match is found, then a rectangular box is drawn around that part of the image which contains the smaller image.

To implement this, I have used the `matchTemplate` method.

The code works as expected, but if the original image's dimensions are 1000 PPI or above, then the image gets cut when displaying the output, hence, the sub-image cannot be highlighted.

Is there a way to fix this?

My code -->

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("C:\Images\big_image.png")
grey_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv2.imread("C:\Images\sub_image.png", 0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

res = cv2.matchTemplate(grey_img, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
print(res)
threshold = 0.9;
loc = np.where(res >= threshold)
print(loc)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `imshow`, call `namedWindow()` with the `WINDOW_NORMAL` flag. That makes it resizable and scales the image to the size of the window.

```py
cv.namedWindow("img", cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
# then imshow()...
```

Comment: Why this is not default behaviour is beyond me. It's even _called_ the "normal" mode....

Comment: the default isn't "normal", it's "autosize", and that means the window resizes to the image, not the other way around. yes, it's that silly. -- 20 years ago, when they started this library, someone just wrote some stuff. then that wasn't reconsidered for a while. then it was made a "stable API". that's how APIs are made.

Comment: Considering the low res displays of that era, it must've been even more of a pain :D

Comment: considering the low res cameras of that era, it wasn't. the videocapture api still tries 640x480 by default, which looks tiny on a 4k retina display. all the gui stuff is scheduled for an overhaul. literally. I don't know how far along they are but it's planned.